# How to link each left and right y-axis in subplots with two y axes

Tags: matlab, plot, axis, handle, figure

I have a figure containing two subplots. Their axes are stored as follows:

```
for i = 1:n
    ax(i) = subplot(n,1,i);
end
```

after plotting, I have attempted to link the axes together. When I do:

```
yyaxis right; linkaxes(ax);
yyaxis left;  linkaxes(ax);
```

I get the right side axes matching, but then the left side of the first figure links to the same scale as the two right side axes, rather than the other left side axis.

I have also tried:

```
yyaxis right; linkprop(ax, 'Ylim')
yyaxis left;  linkprop(ax, 'Ylim')
```

which results in the same problem. I'm trying to find a simple way to have the left y axes link together and the right y axes link together, but remain independent from their opposite axis sides.  Any help would be marvelous.

Comment: "If you have three axes, ax1, ax2, and ax3 and want to link them together, call linkaxes with [ax1, ax2, ax3] as the first argument. Linking ax1 to ax2 and then ax2 to ax3 with separate calls to linkaxes, "unbinds" the ax1-ax2 linkage. linkaxes is not designed to be transitive across multiple invocations."  Have you tried linkaxes([ax(y1), ax(y2), ax(y3), ...etc])

Comment: I'm not sure if I know what you mean, but that didn't seem to have an effect. In essence I have a two subplots, and I want the left size axis limits to be [0 30] and the right side on both to be [0 100]

Answer (score 0):

"linkprop" saves the properties over multiple call (as long as you define the variable "link1, link2..."). For example, I linked the Y axis of the top row, and the Y axis of the bottom row independently. With the third call, I was able to link all the X axis together, keeping the independent link between the Y axis.

Just make sure to save each linkprop call to a different variable

```
  ax{1,1} = subplot(2,2,1);
  ax{1,2} = subplot(2,2,2);
  ax{2,1} = subplot(2,2,3);
  ax{2,2} = subplot(2,2,4);

  link1 = linkprop([ax{1,1},ax{1,2}], 'YLim');
  link2 = linkprop([ax{2,1},ax{2,2}], 'YLim');
  link3 = linkprop([ax{1,1},ax{1,2},ax{2,1},ax{2,2}],'XLim');
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is about using `yyaxis`, not just linking any y axes in different subplots.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that unlike `plotyy`, the use of `yyaxis left` and `yyaxis right` simply creates a second 'NumericRuler' and attaches it to a single axes. Thus we need to start thinking about the use of `linkprop` to link the `Limits` property of each set of left and right rulers, rather than `linkaxes` (since left and right sides share a single axes object).

Here's a display of `ax(1)` showing the two `YAxis` (2 rulers, one for left and one for right) entries: (Note I don't actually know what `YAxisLocation` means as you can see the first `Yaxis` entries corresponds to the left side -- my guess is that this is some strange holdover from also having `plotyy` with multiple axes and being able to move the primary yaxis ruler to the right side)

```
>> ax(1)

ans = 

  Axes with properties:

    YAxisLocation: 'right'
            YAxis: [2×1 NumericRuler]
             YLim: [5 30]
             XLim: [1 10]
           XScale: 'linear'
           YScale: 'linear'
         Position: [0.1300 0.1100 0.3347 0.8150]
            Units: 'normalized'
```

Also, linking the properties doesn't ensure that the entire y-range is covered, so we need to manually determine the y-range to span for each side (left and right), set all ruler limits accordingly, and then link the properties.

Finally, one last tricky part is that linkprop doesn't store its listeners and if you call it multiple times without assigning previous calls to variables the old calls get invalidated.

Here's the final code. Note, this is a completely different setup than what is required if you use `plotyy` which actually creates two axes objects, one on top of the other.

```
n_axes = length(ax);
ax_left = cell(1,n_axes);
ax_right = cell(1,n_axes);
%2 elements is for y-range [min, max]
y_left_limits = zeros(n_axes,2);
y_right_limits = zeros(n_axes,2);

for i = 1:n_axes
    ax_left{i} = ax(i).YAxis(1);
    ax_right{i} = ax(i).YAxis(2);
    y_left_limits(i,:) = ax(i).YAxis(1).Limits;
    y_right_limits(i,:) = ax(i).YAxis(2).Limits;
end

%Need to manually adjust so they encompass
%total range, otherwise value is just copied
%from one to the other

ax_left = [ax_left{:}];
ax_right = [ax_right{:}];

%Update current limits so that entire span of data
%currently visible is shown after linking
%
%otherwise you just get copying of one property to the other
y_lim_left = [min(y_left_limits(:,1)) max(y_left_limits(:,2))];
y_lim_right = [min(y_right_limits(:,1)) max(y_right_limits(:,2))];

for i = 1:n_axes
    ax(i).YAxis(1).Limits = y_lim_left;
    ax(i).YAxis(2).Limits = y_lim_right;
end

%be sure to assign to a variable otherwise
%making the second linkprop call invalidates the first ...
hlink1 = linkprop(ax_left,'Limits');
hlink2 = linkprop(ax_right,'Limits');
```