# make all right and left y-axis limits the same, respectively, for multiple subplots in figure

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, handle, subplot, axes

I have a subplot that appears as follows:

[image]

This is created as follows:

```
fig = figure;
nPlots = 3;
for p = 1:nPlots
  ax(p) = subplot(1, nPlots, p);
  x  = 0:10*p;
  y1 = max(x)-x.^1.1;
  y2 = p*max(x)-2*x;
  yyaxis left;
  plot(x, y1);
  yyaxis right;
  plot(x, y2);
end
```

I want the axes on each side to be the same, respectively, i.e. I want all plots to have:

```
ylim_left  = [0 30];
ylim_right = [0 90];
```

But if I use `linkaxes(ax)` I end up getting only the right side to change:

[image]

If I try `yyaxis left; linkaxes(ax);` then it takes the highest value of the left sides and applies that to the right sides of the first two subplots.

[image]

When I examine ax, I notice all its components ax(1), ax(2)... have the `YAxisLocation:` property set to  `'right'` which I imagine is the root of this problem. I am unsure how to get the handle directly to both the left and right side axes of the subplots to directly link those together. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The trick is that `yyaxis` only creates new rulers on a single axes object. Thus you need to use `linkprop`. My full answer to this question is found in a duplicate question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75537556/764365

Answer (score 1):

Extracting the `NumericRuler` children of your Y axes provides you access to the left and right limits:

```
>> [ax.YAxis]

ans = 

  2×3 NumericRuler array:

    NumericRuler    NumericRuler    NumericRuler
    NumericRuler    NumericRuler    NumericRuler
```

Where Row 1 is the left side and Row 2 is the right side.

Define a helper function to sync these:

```
function matchyyaxes(ax, ylim_L, ylim_R)
yaxes = [ax.YAxis];

set(yaxes(1,:), 'Limits', ylim_L);
set(yaxes(2,:), 'Limits', ylim_R);
end
```

Which you can use with your sample limits:

```
matchyyaxes(ax, [0 30], [0 90]);
```

[image: yay]

---

You could also create your own [property listener](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/handle.addlistener.html) to mimic the functionality of [`linkaxes`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linkaxes.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just insert '`ylim`' functions after plots. This worked for me:

```
fig = figure;
nPlots = 3;
ylim_left  = [0 30];
ylim_right = [0 90];
for p = 1:nPlots
  ax(p) = subplot(1, nPlots, p);
  x  = 0:10*p;
  y1 = max(x)-x.^1.1;
  y2 = p*max(x)-2*x;
  yyaxis left;
  plot(x, y1);
  ylim(ylim_left);
  yyaxis right;
  plot(x, y2);
  ylim(ylim_right);
end
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for responding. This would work, if I already knew the maximum value. I don't in each case, so I want to have something that applies the maximum range to all plots after all have been created.

Comment: OK, then you should first make the calculation and hold the result. Then plot using your loop.